# how can i tell if an application is written with CSLA 2.0 or CSLA 3.5 (or with some other version of CSLA)

Tags: .net, csla

I'm trying to untangle a legacy system written with the CSLA framework. The contractors who originally wrote the software are long gone. I want to figure out what version of CSLA was used so that I can start to learn about that particular framework (and so understand the code). Is there an easy way to do this?

**Edit**
Ideally, by looking for some feature of the CSLA that might indicate the version number.

Answer (score 1):

The change log is [here](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/download.aspx) if specifically the change log for 3.5 is [here](http://www.lhotka.net/Article.aspx?area=4&id=71994329-d218-4c02-a4d4-ce5ea4ac8d4b) so look for the properties mentioned.

Edit - Actually isn't this just a matter of right clicking the DLL and viewing the details tab in properties? Should be listed there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the code is currently compiling then the project should have a reference to the CSLA DLL (called csla.dll, in a well structured project this will be in the business layer code project).  Once you've found that then simply look at the properties of that DLL in visual studio, the Version property is the one that indicates the CSLA version.

Alternatively, look in the apps installation directory in (e.g. in Program Files) and find the CSLA DLL there.  Right click on it, Properties, Details tab and in there Product Version and File Version will both be the CSLA version in use.

Answer (score 0):

I would grab the free version of Telerik JustDecompile, or something similar to that, like Reflector.

These programs can tell you what references are contained within an assembly. (edit: with version information)